# Is the wash sale rule canceled by something if you don't hold the stock in question for 30 days?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, wash-sale

Suppose an inverstor in USA buys 100 shares in XYZ for $50 each. Two weeks later XYZ is doing terribly, and the investor gets cold feet and sells the shares for $40 each, at a total loss of $1000.

Because the sale of XYZ stock happened less than 30 days after he bought XYZ stock, it is classified as a [wash sale according to 26 U.S.C. 1091(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1091), and therefore the investor is not allowed to deduct the loss.

I am seeing insistent claims that the investor is *nevertheless* allowed to deduct his $1000 loss once he has gone 30 days without owning any XYZ stock, but I cannot find any actual rule that says so.

Does such an exception from the wash-sale rule exist, and if so **what is its statutory or regulatory basis**?

Answer (score 5):

You are misunderstanding what constitutes a wash sale.  In your example, the wash sale rules do not apply (as long as you don't buy the stock again for 30 days after the sale).

Let's say that you bought your 100 shares of XYZ for $50 each.  At some point in the future, the price drops to $40.  You think that the price will bounce back and you want to continue to hold, but you would like to deduct the loss on your taxes.  Therefore, you decide that you will sell XYZ at $40 (for a total loss of $1000), but you repurchase the stock again (also at $40).  The transaction cost you nothing (as you sold and bought at the same price), and you still own 100 shares of XYZ, but now you think you have a $1000 loss to deduct.  However, *the wash sale rule exists to prohibit the deduction under this circumstance.*

In your example, at the end of the story the investor no longer owns the stock.  Therefore, as long as 30 days go by without him owning the stock, the wash sale rules do not apply.  The investor legitimately lost $1000, and can take the deduction.  After 30 days go by, the investor is free to buy again, if he wishes, and start a brand new cost basis.

Here is how to correctly parse the tax code you cited:

[26 U.S. Code § 1091 - Loss from wash sales of stock or securities](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1091)

> **(a) Disallowance of loss deduction**
>
> In the case of any loss claimed to have been sustained from any sale or other disposition of shares of stock or securities where it appears that, within a period beginning 30 days before the date of such sale or disposition and ending 30 days after such date, the taxpayer has acquired (by purchase or by an exchange on which the entire amount of gain or loss was recognized by law), or has entered into a contract or option so to acquire, substantially identical stock or securities, then no deduction shall be allowed under section 165 unless the taxpayer is a dealer in stock or securities and the loss is sustained in a transaction made in the ordinary course of such business. For purposes of this section, the term “stock or securities” shall, except as provided in regulations, include contracts or options to acquire or sell stock or securities.

The 100 shares that you sold at a loss were the 100 shares that you purchased 2 weeks earlier.  That purchase transaction doesn't count.  You legitimately have a "loss claimed to have been sustained from any sale or other dispostion of shares of stock."  The next part of the sentence says, "where it appears that, within a period..., the taxpayer has acquired... **substantially identical stock or securities**, then no deduction shall be allowed."  This has not happened.  You did not dispose of some shares, and then within the period purchase additional identical shares.  You had no shares to start, you bought them, you sold them at a loss, and ended with no shares.  This is not a wash sale under these rules.  The shares that you purchased 2 weeks earlier was not a purchase of substantially identical shares.  It was the initial purchase of the shares that you sold.

The tax code is very hard to read, and can be misleading if you aren't used to looking at it.  The IRS issues publications that are intended to be more clear and easier to parse.  IRS Publication 550 has [this to say about wash sales](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550#en_US_2017_publink100010601):

> A wash sale occurs when you sell or trade stock or securities at a loss and within 30 days before or after the sale you:
>
> - Buy substantially identical stock or securities,
> - Acquire substantially identical stock or securities in a fully taxable trade,
> - Acquire a contract or option to buy substantially identical stock or securities, or
> - Acquire substantially identical stock for your individual retirement account (IRA) or Roth IRA.

It says that in order to have a wash sale, you must **sell the stock at a loss** and you must **acquire substantially identical stock** within the window.  In your example, the second part has not occurred.  The investor sold the stock at a loss, but he did not acquire substantially identical stock.  The first purchase was the purchase of the stock he sold for a loss.

The publication goes on to list 4 examples, each of which shows a wash sale.  In every example, the investor is shown buying stock at some point in the past that is not in the window.  It is the purchase of additional identical shares before or after the sale of the old shares that makes it a wash sale.

---

Here is the important thing to note about the wash sale rule that you may be missing.  Yes, the wash sale rule, when triggered, prevents you from taking a capital loss deduction.  However, it does not prevent you from taking the loss forever; instead, you add the loss to the cost basis of the shares you still have.

For example, let's say that I buy 100 shares of stock for $50.  A year later, I sell those 100 shares for $40, and just before I did that, I purchased 100 shares at $45.  Wash sale rules prevent me from deducting the loss now, but I can take that $10 per share loss and add it to the cost basis of the shares I still have.  The cost basis of the 100 shares I have is now $55, and when I sell them in the future, this reduces the capital gain I will have (or increases the capital loss).

In your example, there are no remaining shares with which to add on to the cost basis.  The wash sale rule doesn't even make sense in this scenario, because there is nothing remaining on which to tack on the loss.

Comment: How does the situation in my story _not_ match the condition in the statutory provision I linked to? Every element in the statutory rule appears to me to be satisfied. For example, I see nothing in §1091(a) to the effect of "but only if the entire transaction cost you nothing" or "but only if the taxpayer has any stock left after these transactions".

Comment: You write "That purchase transaction doesn't count". My question is exactly _what makes it not count_, because it exactly matches the description in the paragraph you have now also quoted. (1) It **appears that** -- I'm stipulating this. (2) **within the period** -- the purchase happened 2 weeks before the sale, easily within the period (3) **taxpayer has acquired** -- yes he bought the shared (4) **substantially identical stock** -- the stock bought was _exactly identical_ to the stock sold. It is not possible to be any more identical.

Comment: "You did not dispose of some shares, and **then** within the period purchase additional identical shares." No, but the statute exactly and explicitly does not apply only in that order of events.

Comment: "You had no shares to start, you bought them, you sold them at a loss, and ended with no shares". Yes, exactly. And I still see no text in the statute that says that it would not apply in that situation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The investor did not purchase “substantially identical stock.”  The purchase we are talking about was the purchase of the actual shares we are talking about selling. True, the order doesn’t matter in a wash sale. In an actual wash sale circumstance, where the investor had shares before our transactions in question, then purchases 100 more shares and sells 100 shares 2 weeks later, wash sale rules would indeed apply.

Comment: My question is where the condition that "the investor had had shares before our transactions in question" (meaning the sale as well as the acquisition that triggers the rule) comes from. I cannot see it in the statutory text, and I had hoped this question would give me a pointer to official IRS regulations (or case law or whatever) that explicitly says something like "the actual text notwithstanding, this paragraph will be interpreted to only apply under such-and-such additional conditions".

Comment: (Also I'm somewhat mystified by your claim that my investor did not purchase "substantially identical stock". The purchase was of _the very same stock_ that he later sold. If _the same_ stock doesn't count as "substantially identical", that would be a complete loophole -- it would mean you could get to deduct your loss by selling to your cousin (who never held any other XYZ stock) and buying the same stock back from him later. Surely in _that_ case you wouldn't be able to argue "this is not a wash sale because it was the very same stock I bought back and thus not _substantially identical_").

Comment: @HenningMakholm I’m not familiar with US tax law and on the face of it you’re right. But I suspect that if what you described actually *isn’t* a wash sale and the extract in this answer is all we had to go on, the reason would likely turn on the wording *substantially equivalent* being interpreted as implying a *different* lot of securities than the lot that was sold.

Comment: @Lawrence: I assume your comment must have crossed my comment just above :-)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have added a quote from IRS Pub 550 that I believe helps clarify.

Comment: Rather than repeat myself, let me refer to the "Also I'm somewhat mystified" comment above.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes :) . I was using the phone app and didn't notice any updates while entering my comment. The [Australian](https://www.ato.gov.au/law/view/document?DocID=TPA/TA20087/NAT/ATO/00001) wording is clearer  (emphasis, mine): "The type of wash sale arrangement this alert covers is where a taxpayer disposes of, or otherwise deals with a capital gains tax (CGT) asset to generate a capital or revenue loss, but where in substance, there is **no significant change in the taxpayer's economic exposure in the asset**." So if you sold the stock but somehow hung on to it, it's a wash sale.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have added further explanation about how the wash sale rule is actually applied, and showed that your example doesn't meet this.  I'm sorry that you are having trouble wrapping your head around this.  I hope someone else can post an answer that explains this in a way that makes sense to you.

Comment: My trouble is not with understanding how it's actually applied in practice -- I don't doubt your and Bob's claims about that. It just doesn't really help me know what the _legal textual basis_ for that actual application is, which is what I was trying to ask. I'm reluctant to think that a government would just, out of the goodness of its heart, choose to let people to pay less in tax if they have a statute at their disposal that on its face would allow them to demand more. So there must be some explicit text _somewhere_ that forces the different reading. My goal is to find that somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You do not understand what a wash sale is.

The first paragraph of your link provides the answer.

> (a) Disallowance of loss deduction
>
> In the case of any loss claimed to have been sustained from any sale or other disposition of shares of stock or securities where it appears that, within a period beginning 30 days before the date of such sale or disposition and ending 30 days after such date** , the taxpayer has acquired (by purchase or by an exchange on which the entire amount of gain or loss was recognized by law), or has entered into a contract or option so to acquire, ** substantially identical stock or securities** , then no deduction shall be allowed under section 165 unless the taxpayer is a dealer in stock or securities and the loss is sustained in a transaction made in the ordinary course of such business. For purposes of this section, the term “stock or securities” shall, except as provided in regulations, include contracts or options to acquire or sell stock or securities.

The disallowance occurs because of the acquisition of a second lot of the security involved in the loss.

In your example of purchasing 100 shares of XYZ for $50 each and selling them two weeks later for $40 each, there is no second purchase hence there can be no wash sale.  The is simply a capital loss of $1,000

> > I am seeing insistent claims that the investor is nevertheless allowed to deduct his $1000 loss once he has gone 30 days without owning any XYZ stock, but I cannot find any actual rule that says so.

Technically, it is 60 days (30 days before and 30 days after).

Comment: I'm going from the statute's definition of what a wash sale is -- the very one you have helpfully quoted here. Which of the conditions in that paragraph is not satisfied in my story?

Comment: In particular the statute **explicitly** says that it is still a wash sale if the purchase happened _before_ the sale as it did in my story. I see no requirement that the purchase must be a "second" purchase -- a single purchase is enough to trigger the rule according to its language if that single purchase happens **within a period beginning 30 days before the date of such sale or disposition and ending 30 days after such date**.

Comment: For a long position, a wash sale involves two purchases and one sale (with the aforementioned loss and 60 day window).  What's wrong with your story is that it involves one purchase and one sale which means that it is categorically impossible to be a wash sale.  The problem is that you keep insisting that your trade is a wash sale without understanding what a wash sale is.

Comment: Could you please point me to where in the statute or regulations is says that "a wash sale involves two purchases".

Comment: I don't claim anything in particular about the word "wash sale", but I do claim that what I have described is a transaction that the rule explicitly says it applies to, no matter whether one _calls_ it a "wash sale" or not. The rule does not depend on that phases -- instead it contains a self-contained description of when it applies and when it doesn't.,

Comment: It says it right there in paragraph one of your link:"In the case of any LOSS claimed to have been sustained from any SALE or other DISPOSITION of shares of stock or securities where it appears that, WITHIN a period beginning 30 days BEFORE the date of such sale or disposition and ending 30 days AFTER such date** , the taxpayer has ACQUIRED (by purchase or by an exchange on which the entire amount of gain or loss was recognized by law), or has entered into a contract or option so to acquire, SUBSTANTIALLY IDENTICAL stock or securities

Comment: I don't see what you get out of repeatedly quoting the text without even trying to explain what in the text would mean that it does not apply to my example. And, no the scattered capitalization of words in that text does not help me understand why you think it does not describe my example.

Comment: There is no freedom of choice in this matter.  You don't get the opportunity to "call it a wash sale or not".  If the transaction meet the criteria for a wash sale violation, then that's what it is, and the deduction is postponed.   If they do not then it is simply a capital loss and the deduction can be claimed immediately.  .

Comment: The transaction I'm describing meets the criteria explicitly set out in the rule that I have linked to once and you have quoted twice. There is a "loss ... sustatined from [a] sale .. of shares ... where ... within a period beginning 30 days before [the sale] ... the taxpayer has acquired ... identical stock". If you don't think this describes my transaction, please indicate **specifically** which words in the black-on-white text of the condition cause it to fail.

Comment: In your example, you bought 100 shares in XYZ for $50 each and then sold them two weeks later  for $40 each.  That is not a WASH SALE.

Comment: If you cannot substantiate that claim with actual references to actual words in the text I have linked to once and you have quoted twice, then just don't bother repeating it.

Comment: IRS Publication 550, page 58: WASH SALES.  Read it and then get back to us.

Comment: You have pointed to that page already, and I don't see anything there that contradicts the statutory definition. Just because the examples it gives are not like my hypothetical does not imply that the rule itself is constrained to apply only to facts that (to some degree) resemble those particular examples. In particular there are _no_ examples on that page where the triggering purchase happens before the sale-with-loss, but the statutory text is nevertheless explicit that it _can_ apply in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

In the other Question chain which prompted this Question, you asked for a citation explaining the Wash Sale Rule.  Here's one froma reliable source:

> What is the 'Wash-Sale Rule'
>
> The wash-sale rule is an Internal Revenue Service (IRS) regulation established to disallow a tax deduction for a security sold in a wash sale. The rule defines a wash sale as one that occurs when an individual sells or trades a security at a loss and, within 30 days before or after this sale, buys a “substantially identical” stock or security, or acquires a contract or option to do so. A wash sale also results if an individual sells a security, and the spouse or a company controlled by the individual buys a substantially equivalent security.
>
> BREAKING DOWN 'Wash-Sale Rule'
>
> The intent of the wash-sale rule is to prevent taxpayers from claiming artificial losses. Conversely, if a taxpayer were to see a gain by selling securities, and within 30 days he or she were to buy identical replacement securities, the proceeds from that transaction would still be taxable. The sale of options, which are quantified in the same ways as stocks, at a loss and reacquisition of identical options in the 30-day timeframe would also fall under the terms of the wash-sale rule. So the wash-sale period is actually 61 days, consisting of the 30 days before to 30 days after the date of sale.
>
> For example, you buy 100 shares of XYZ tech stock on November 1 for $10,000. On December 15, the value of the 100 shares has declined to $7,000, so you sell the entire position to realize a capital loss of $3,000 for tax deduction purposes. On December 27 of the same year, you repurchase the 100 shares of XYZ tech stock back again to reestablish your position in the stock. The initial loss will be not be allowed since the security was repurchased within the limited time interval.

Wash-Sale Rule https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/washsalerule.asp#ixzz5X9pg3C5F

Comment: Does someone's understanding of the "intent of the rule" trump what the rule _actually says_?

Comment: The intent of the wash sale rule?  It was designed to prevent investors from selling a security at a loss and immediately repurchasing it (or transacting in the reverse order)  so that they could generate losses that could be used to reduce their taxable income.

Comment: @HenningMakholm judges in areas that operate law of precedent interpret intent and applicability of precedent all of the time so the person interpreting could easily trump the actual wording. If the author of the Investopedia was legally minded enough to have checked the results of legal cases that to could be more accurate in practice than the literal wording.