# Why is VTI a wash sale, but VV is not?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, wash-sale

Here is my Fidelity YTD tax report on short-term losses.  Why does it show a wash sale disallowed loss for the VTI holding, but not for the VV holding?

[2018 YTD ST Losses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXeil.png)

Comment: Thanks for the analyses.  They are very helpful.  I am intrigued by Bob Baerker's statement that "Wash sales are not an issue [if] an entire position is closed out by the end of the year."  This "rule" is what got me to the StackExchange.  But where does this rule come from?  It's not in the statute or rules.  It would seem to mean that I can (1) go through all my losers for the year and, (2) if I make certain I am closing out all my positions in them (and stay out of them for the rest of the year), reap some great tax losses before the end of the year.

Comment: Where does the wash sale rule come from?  See IRS pub 550 (page 58 - Wash Sales).  Yes,  you  can (1) go through all of your losers for the year and (2) if  you close out all positions in them (and stay out of them for 30 DAYS AFTER REALIZING THE LOSS), then you can deduct up to the limit of $3,000 in losses after netting out gains against losses.

Comment: No, my ? was about the legal basis for the rule of "Wash sales are not an issue [if] an entire position is closed out by the end of the year"?  Or is it just that closing ones entire position for a loss indicates that there must be a non-tax reason for taking the loss.  I.e. if the reason for the rule (to deter losses incurred solely for tax purposes) doesn't apply, don't apply the rule?  I would feel a whole lot better about relying on the "close-out" exception if there was a Revenue Ruling somewhere that explained it and said it was a valid application of the wash sale rule.

Comment: The legal basis of the rule is that the IRS makes the rules.  Losses are allowed.   The intent of the wash sale rule  is to prevent you from creating artificial losses, namely closing the position to realize a loss and then immediately opening it to restore the position (or executed in reverse order).  IOW, the IRS wants tax revenue this year not next year.

Comment: About the rule of "Wash sales are not an issue [if] an entire position is closed out by the end of the year," is there something significant about it being at "the end of the year"?  I have good losses to harvest by closing all my positions in VOO before the end of the year.  But the market is creeping back up.  Could I still close out my positions on 1/6 or 1/7/19 and avoid a wash sale?  (Of course, it would then be a 2019 loss.)

Comment: From your questions. I'm not sure if you completely understand the wash sale.  If you buy replacement shares or anything substantially identical (a long call on that security) within 30 days BEFORE realizing the loss or within 30 days AFTER, it's a wash sale and some portion (or all) of the loss may be disallowed and must then be carried forward. Precise phrasing on my part would have been that  the entire position is closed "BY the end of the year" (and not repurchased within 30 days on either side in order to eliminate the carry forward.

Comment: You can close a position whenever you want.  The date determines the tax year your report it in  and repurchases date determines if there are any wash sales.  If there's a carry forward wash sale and the entire position is not closed in the current tax year then the loss in question gets carried forward to the next year.  People should also be aware that DRIP purchases within the 60 day window can trigger a wash sale violation.

Comment: What's a DRIP purchase?  What's a "long call" on a security?

Comment: DRIP = Dividend ReInvestment Plan.  A call is an option that gives you the right to buy the security.  Google the terms for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: Oh.  I don't have DRIP and I don't do calls or puts.  Sorry to be so thick about this.  So, to confirm, I sold VTV on 12/10 and bought VOO on 12/17.  Now VOO is down a lot and I'd like to sell to take the loss in 2018 (and I don't own any other VOO anywhere).  So I sell today and that's not a wash sale.

Comment: The wash sale rule is simple and explicit. Buying substantially identical securities within 30 days on either side of a realized loss is a wash sale.  Look at your purchase and sale dates and determine what trade(s) have violated or will violate this rule and what trade(s) will not.

Comment: So, if your having bought the very shares you are selling does not make the sale of those shares within 30 days a wash sale, what is an example of a wash sale where the substantially identical replacement shares were purchased *before* the sale?

Comment: IRS pub 550, page 58.  EXAMPLE 1. You buy 100 shares of X stock for $1,000. You sell these shares for $750 and within 30 days from the sale you buy 100 shares of the same stock for $800. Because you bought substantially identical stock, you cannot deduct your loss of $250 on the sale. However, you add the disallowed loss of $250 to the cost of the new stock, $800, to obtain your basis in the new stock, which is $1,050. Definition of 'within' means 30 days before or 30 days after.

Comment: That's a standard example.  What I am after is this situation. You buy 100 shares of X stock for $1,000 on Jan 3, then buy another 100 shares of X stock on Jan 18.  On Jan 30 you sell the 100 shares you bought on Jan 18 for a loss (designating them as being the Jan 18 shares in the lot designation of your order), but you keep the Jan 3 shares.  Is the Jan 30 sale a wash sale.

Comment: I would suggest that you  re-read  the explanations provided by multiple people as well as the link citations and then apply that information to your various hypotheticals.  It's a simple rule and all you have to do is determine if shares are replacement shares or not.  If you cannot do that, subscribe to  a Schedule D tax preparation  program that does this flawlessly (such as Tradelog or Gainskeeper) OR consult with an accountant.  Good luck.

Comment: Well, so much for this being a place where you can get answers . . .

Answer (score 2):

The sale on 4/2 was a wash sale because of the purchase on 3/16. Note that the disallowed loss causes an adjustment to the basis of the purchase on 3/16, which was subsequently sold, so you actually do get the tax benefit of the loss.

For the sale on 12/17, there was no additional purchase within the wash sale period, so there’s no reason for it to be a wash sale. However, the period extends into next year, so if you purchase more VV within that period, then that may be a wash sale, too.

Answer (score 1):

Wash sales are not an issue an entire position is closed out by the end of the year.  If they are not, the loss deduction is disallowed and must be carried forward.

For VV, there is no date acquired or date sold info.  I'm guessing that the position was acquired over time (multiple dates), hence the reason for not listing these.  I'm also going to guess that even if there were wash sale violations within the period of ownership then because you sold your entire (?) position of VV shares in 2018, then there is no wash sale carryover violation and you are allowed to deduct the full loss.

The 350   shares of VTI sold for a loss on 4/02 was a wash sale because you bought back shares on 4/22 and that  violated the 60 day window  (30 days before or 30 days after). I would assume that  you did not sell off  your entire position in VTI and therefore, the loss has been disallowed and must be carried forward to next year.

In order to accurately analyze this, a chronological list of all trades since the first purchase would be needed and honestly, I'm not going there.  Ironically, I spent half the day today collating my 2018 trades to determine what my wash sales situation looks like and where I have carryover issues.  Where possible, I'm going to close the entire position this coming week  to reduce/eliminate  the bookkeeping headache.

If any of my guesses or assumptions are incorrect then move on to the next answer, if any :->)

Comment: The VV was a one-time purchase on 12/10 and sold on 12/17 for a loss.

Comment: Since it was a one time purchase and complete sale of shares, it wasn't a wash sale.  You didn't buy shares within a 60 day period around the date that you realized the loss (30 days before and 30 days after).

Answer (score 0):

A wash sale occurs if you buy *replacement shares* for those you sell at a loss, within 30 days before or after the sale. The actual shares you sell are not replacement shares even if they were bought less than 30 days before. In VTI, your loss realized on April 2 was disallowed because you bought replacement shares on March 16. In VV, you had only one purchase and one sale, so there were no replacement shares.

A good explanation of the wash sale rule is [here](https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/wash/).

The intent is to prevent you from deducting a loss that you have not *genuinely* realized. If you buy replacement shares around the same time as the sale, then from a risk perspective, you essentially remain invested the whole time -- the purchase and sale are likely to occur at similar prices and are thus a "wash". It would be a giant loophole if people could effectively deduct unrealized losses, while also not being taxed on unrealized gains.

Comment: Here's another rule that everyone here seems to accept, but I don't see anything in the statute or rules about: "The actual shares you sell are not replacement shares even if they were bought less than 30 days before."  My buying the VV shares a week before I sold them for a loss certainly seems to come within the letter of the rule -- they were bought within in the 30 days before the loss sale.  Is there some revenue ruling defining which identical stock bought within the 30 days before a loss sale is a "replacement" and which identical stock bought in the same period of time is not?

Comment: @Bill That has been asked [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/102173/is-the-wash-sale-rule-canceled-by-something-if-you-dont-hold-the-stock-in-quest).

Comment: Went to the comment you linked to, thanks.  Like the protagonist there, I still don't see the result you argue for in the text of the rule (and I'm a law professor used to complex federal statutes).  But since it really helps me in generating losses, I will take your word for it and use in good health.  As my father advised me as young man, if one person accuses you of being drunk when you are not, you can ignore it.  If 2 people do, think about it seriously.  But if 3 people accuse you of being drunk when you are not, go home and go to bed.

Comment: I should add that it doesn't bother me that the result of the discussion you sent me concludes essentially that the literal meaning of a rule does not apply to situations that don't come within the intent of the rule.   The famous US S Ct case on this is Holy Trinity Episcopal Church, where a federal statute made it unlawful for anyone to assist in the migration of “any alien . . . under contract or agreement . . . to perform labor or service of any kind in the United States.”  Holy Trinity Church was prosecuted when it hired an Englishman to come to the United States to be its pastor.

Comment: Despite the fact that the English pastor came within the wording of the statute, the Supreme Court held that the church had not violated it. It observed that the “evil” at which the statute was directed was importation of “an ignorant and servile class of foreign laborers” who agreed to work “at a low rate of wages,” thus “break[ing] down the labor market.”  Since “it was this cheap unskilled labor which was making the trouble” and it was never suggested that “the market for the services of Christian ministers was depressed by foreign competition,” the statute would not apply.

Comment: In this post-Scalia era of following the "plain meaning" of the statute, I don't know that the Ct would go as far as it did in the Holy Trinity case (that was in 1892).  But Bob's reading of the text of the statute --- to apply only to "replacement" purchases, and not the original purchase that was admittedly within the 30 day period before the loss sale --- isn't nearly the stretch that result in the Holy Trinity decision is.

Comment: And Rev Ruling Rev. Ruling 56-602 (which clarifies that you disregard shares acquired at the same time as shares sold when applying the wash sale rule -- closely analogous to share bought within 30 days before) discusses statutory intent: "Congressional discussions and reports refer consistently to the ‘new acquisition’ and to ‘repurchasing’ and ‘buying back’ stock or securities. These terms indicate an intent on the part of Congress to prevent a taxpayer’s taking losses for tax purposes while giving up his position in a security for only a few days or not at all. [cont'd]

Comment: However, they do not indicate an intent to disallow a loss sustained in a bona fide sale of securities made to reduce the taxpayer’s holdings, even though the sale is made within 30 days after the securities were purchased.”

Comment: This is starting to feel like asking someone what time it is and being told how to build a clock.  The wash sale rule is simple and explicit.  Buying substantially identical securities within 30 days on either side of a realized loss is a wash sale.